# Formulario modal con focus en input incompleto

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, bootstrap

tengo un formulario `modal` con `tabs` realizado con `bootstrap 4`

Este es mi formulario modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo ubicar el focus en cada input de mi formulario??** lo que necesito es lo siguiente: si al presionar el boton guardar existen campos que no pasan las validaciones que estableci en mi request. Necesito que me lleve al campo respectivo para poder completarlo.
Lo que busco es que me lleve a la pestaña correcta y al campo incompleto y así con cada campo vacio donde se requiera la validación, he probado con esto.

este mi request

```
class ClientStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre_cliente'    => 'required|alpha|min:3|max:20',
            'apellido'          => 'required|alpha|min:4|max:50',
            'email'             => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email|max:100',
            'nombre_empresa'    => 'required|string|min:3|max:20',
            'registro_fiscal'   => 'required|alpha_dash|min:13|max:15',
            'telefono'          => 'required|numeric|min:10',
            'telefono_contacto' => 'required|numeric|min:11'
        ];
    }
```

este es mi formulario:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_agregar" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form_agregar" method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.clientes.store') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Nuevo Cliente</h4>
      </div>      
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">        
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab" id="empresa">Empresa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab" id="contacto">Contacto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" id="direccion">Dirección</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-horizontal"> 
          <div class="tab-content" >             
            <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">             
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre_empresa" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre empresa" id="nombre_empresa" name="nombre_empresa">                   

                  </div>
              </div>               
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="registro_fiscal" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Registro fiscal</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuil" id="registro_fiscal" name="registro_fiscal">

                </div>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sitio_web" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sitio Web</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="url" class="form-control" id="sitio_web" name="sitio_web">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Teléfono</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono empresa" id="telefono" name="telefono">

                </div>
              </div>              
            </div>           
            <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">             
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre_cliente" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombres</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres" id="nombre_cliente" name="nombre_cliente">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellido" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" id="apellido" name="apellido">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electronico" id="email" name="email">

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono_contacto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Teléfono</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono contacto" id="telefono_contacto" name="telefono_contacto">

                </div>
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">               
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="calle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Calle</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calle" name="calle">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ciudad" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ciudad</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="provincia" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Región/Provincia</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="provincia" name="provincia">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="codigo_postal" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Código Postal</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo_postal" name="codigo_postal">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pais" class="col-sm-3 control-label">País</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <select class="form-control" name="pais_id" id="pais_id">
                    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>       
                    <option value="1">Argentina</option>                                                                
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>             
            </div>          
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" id="guardar_datos" class="btn btn-primary add">Registrar</button>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>  
</form>  
</div>
```

este mi `script`:

```
 $.ajax({
          data: $('#form_agregar').serialize(),
          url: "{{ route('customers.clientes.store') }}",         
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data){
            $('#form_agregar').trigger('reset');         
            $('#modal_agregar').modal('hide'); 
            $('#clientes_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();  
            swal({
                type : 'success',
                title : 'Success!',
                text : 'Data has been saved!'
            });
          },
          error : function(xhr){
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if($.isEmptyObject(res) == false){
              $.each(res.errors, function (key, value){
                $('#' + key)
                  .closest('.form-group').find('div:first')                
                  .addClass('has-error')                                 
                  .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');
                  $('#empresa').tab('show');
                    $('#nombre_empresa').focus();
                    $('#registro_fiscal').focus();
                    $('#telefono').focus();
                  $('#contacto').tab('show');
                    $('#nombre_cliente').focus();
                    $('#apellido').focus();
                    $('#email').focus();
                    $('#telefono_contacto').focus();
              });
            } 
          }
        });
      });
```

**tienen algun ejemplo con ajax???**
Gracias por leerme!!!

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor publicar el código HTML? Por favor. Como recomendación diría que lo mejor es validar primero que todos los campos del formulario estén llenos añadiendo el atributo required a los input, esto dará el foco automáticamente, luego de que pase la validación sí harías el envío.

Comment: ¿Porqué no envías por ajax y compruebas los campos de cada pestaña en el momento en que tratas de cambiar de pestaña?

Comment: @Orici no termino de comprenderte me ayudarias con un ejemplo concreto ?